# Why is my new .gitignore automatically ignored?

Tags: git, bash, redirect, gitignore

So, after converting my repository to git and doing the first build, some build directories showed up in `git status`:

```
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   build.xml
#       modified:   src/ant/common-tasks.xml
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       classes/
#       doku/
#       texdoku/
#       tmp/
```

So, of course I need a `.gitignore`, and since I didn't want to type these directory-names again, I used this command:

```
git status -s | grep '?' | cut -b 4- > .gitignore
```

Since `git status -s` showed this

```
 M build.xml
 M src/ant/common-tasks.xml
?? classes/
?? doku/
?? texdoku/
?? tmp/
```

before, I assumed the new `.gitignore` file to contain these lines:

```
classes/
doku/
texdoku/
tmp/
```

But then:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   build.xml
#       modified:   src/ant/common-tasks.xml
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Yes, it ignored the four directories, but also the new `.gitignore` file. Why?

```
$ git add .gitignore
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
.gitignore
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Huh. Why is my `.gitignore` ignored? I remember that in the last project I could add it to the repository. I searched quite a time, and googled what else could cause this file to be ignored - `.git/info/excludes` has only commented lines, and all parent-directories up to `/` have no `.gitignore`. Also `git config core.excludesfile` shows nothing.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git status -s | grep '?' | cut -b 4- > .gitignore
```

The `> .gitignore` redirection at the end of the pipeline created the `.gitignore` file **before** `git status` did its directory listing. So, in fact the result was

```
.gitignore
classes/
doku/
texdoku/
tmp/
```

which got written in the `.gitignore` file. Thus, the `.gitignore` ignored itself. Editing the file to remove the first line solved the problem, of course.

Comment: You outsmarted yourself! I like the auto-creation of the .gitignore, though, and use of the relatively new `git status -s`, very nice. (By the way, `--porcelain` is currently the same as `-s,--short`, but is guaranteed not to change its output format.)