# How can ls see the future when using bash redirection?

Tags: bash, redirect

I meet the following code in a book and still not understand why. Anyone can help to explain it please?

```
[root@wd00070319 test]# ls
[root@wd00070319 test]# touch file1
[root@wd00070319 test]# ls
file1
[root@wd00070319 test]# ls > file2
[root@wd00070319 test]# ls
file1  file2
[root@wd00070319 test]# cat file2
file1
file2
[root@wd00070319 test]#
```

Comment: touch file will update the last access time and you add the content of the directory inside a file2 and print its contentwith cat

Comment: Could any of the two persons that voted "off-topic" explain why?

Comment: A similar example: [new .gitignore automatically ignored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399628/new-gitignore-automatically-ignored)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[root@wd00070319 test]# ls            # list the files. (directory is empty!)
[root@wd00070319 test]# touch file1   # create an empty file called "file1"
[root@wd00070319 test]# ls            # list the files again (to see "file1")
file1                                 
[root@wd00070319 test]# ls > file2    # list the files, put the result in "file2"
[root@wd00070319 test]# ls            # list the files again,
file1  file2
[root@wd00070319 test]# cat file2     # show content of file2
file1
file2                                 # <-- Note that "file2" is present as well.
[root@wd00070319 test]#
```

The lesson here is probably that a command like `ls > file2` creates the output-file (`file2`) *before* actually executing the `ls` command.

---

This behavior is confirmed by the bash reference manual:

> **3.6 Redirections**
>
> [...] ***Before*** a command is executed, its input and output may be redirected
>   using a special notation interpreted by the shell. [...]

Comment: yeah but the OP's doubt is how come file2 is inserted in file2 before `ls > file2` .i assume that file2 is created before the redirection happens. and thats why in the statement `ls>file2` `ls` will list file2 as well

Comment: That's what I wrote at the bottom

Comment: but you have used a word `probably`.but where is the confirmation for that.could you please provide  a reference if you have?

Comment: Obviously I wrote "probably" because I can't tell *for sure* that this is the lesson. (And NO, I don't have any reference for whether or not that is indeed the lessen of the excerpt.) (Added another reference for you.)

Comment: If you think about it, it *has* to create the `file2` before launching the `ls` command, so that the `ls` command has a file to write its output to.